# how to solve TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in python

Tags: python, json

**The Situation**

I am trying to access values within a json string but receive the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

**The JSON**

```
        j={
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        2.44775,
                        48.925778
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "country_code": "fr",
                    "housenumber": "15",
                    "street": "Rue Leon Bernard",
                    "distance": 16.948223707815888,
                    "country": "France",
                    "county": "Seine-Saint-Denis",
                    "datasource": {
                        "sourcename": "openaddresses",
                        "attribution": "© OpenAddresses contributors",
                        "license": "BSD-3-Clause License"
                    },
                    "postcode": "93700",
                    "state": "Ile-of-France",
                    "district": "Drancy",
                    "city": "Drancy",
                    "lon": 2.44775,
                    "lat": 48.925778,
                    "result_type": "building",
                    "formatted": "15 Rue Leon Bernard, 93700 Drancy, France",
                    "address_line1": "15 Rue Leon Bernard",
                    "address_line2": "93700 Drancy, France",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

**The Objective**

I need to get the value of country_code and country i have tried

```json
j['features']['properties'][0]`
```

**The Question:**

How can i get the value of these two fields in python ?

Comment: `j['features'][0]['properties']['country_code']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the json that you provided the 'features' value is a list, thus you need to index it accordingly.

```json
j['features'][0]['properties']
```

From here you should be able to simply continue to access all the values of 'properties'